# Why isn't the auto-increment working?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Installed MySQL literally 1 hour ago, most likely it's a very stupid mistake from my side.

So, even though I check the boxes for Auto-increment and Zero-Filling, the table sections still come out as NULL, even if I hit the apply / refresh buttons thousands of times. What am I missing?

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try inserting some data.

Comment: I don't see any data in the table -- Put something in fname, lname and grade -- leaving ID blank and it should auto increment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a 'nothing found' result from MySQL Workbench, it actually correlates to zero rows - this is how Workbench denotes end of fetched records. Your table is currently empty at the moment, it is just how Workbench shows things.

Comment: Wow, I never liked Workbench, but that's truly horrid.

Comment: Oh ok, I see. That just seemed weird to me that it was showing NULL. Also to me it seems weird that the auto-increment check in the bottom is gray (non-clickable) while the one in the top is working fine, it's the same button after all like [here](https://imgur.com/a/7cyUp)

Comment: @Sciencephile It is weird. I'd have made the same mistake - assuming that's a single row of all-null data. What a weird thing to show instead of something like "empty table" or "no rows returned" or whatnot.